# How to consolidate a dataset in Kaggle?

Tags: directory, dataset, kaggle

I have an image dataset of 6.5 GB.

Since it is so huge, I divided the dataset into three batches and uploaded them on Kaggle.  Each time, I created a new version of the dataset to upload a new batch.  Now, the problem is, my dataset is present in three different folders.  I want my dataset to be stored in a single folder.

The structure of my dataset looks like this:
[Dataset Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe1eS.png)

Basically, I want the `Data`, `Dataset` and `Dataset2` folders in a single folder.  How do I do this?